# how to use save point in db2 procedure?

Tags: db2

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE mastertb.proc_save_permanent_certificate(IN in_app_no VARCHAR(20),OUT out_response VARCHAR(20))   
BEGIN  
    DECLARE vpermanent_prim_key INTEGER;  
    DECLARE ventitymast_appno INTEGER;  
    DECLARE EXPECTED_dAYS INTEGER;    
    SAVEPOINT STOP_HERE ON ROLLBACK;
    SELECT NEXT_SEQUENCE INTO vpermanent_prim_key FROM 
    MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_NEXT_SEQUENCE WHERE 
    UCASE(NAME)='MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_PERMANENT_RESIDENCE_CERTIFICATE';  
    SET vpermanent_prim_key = vpermanent_prim_key + 1;  
    SELECT NEXT_SEQUENCE INTO ventitymast_appno FROM 
    MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_NEXT_SEQUENCE WHERE 
    NAME= 'mastertb.Z_ENTITYMAST_SAVED_APPLICATION';  
    SET ventitymast_appno=ventitymast_appno+1;

    SELECT EXPECTED_DAYS_REQUIRED INTO EXPECTED_dAYS FROM 
    MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_SERVICELIST WHERE SERVICE_ID=1;
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( 'primary key value = '||vpermanent_prim_key);
    CALL DBMS_OUTPUT.NEW_LINE;
    INSERT INTO   
    MASTERTB.z_entitymast_permanent_residence_certificate(APP_NO,DEP_ID, 
    PERMANENT_RESIDENCE_ID,CREATED_DATE )   
    VALUES (in_app_no,vpermanent_prim_key, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP );  
    UPDATE MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_NEXT_SEQUENCE SET 
    NEXT_SEQUENCE=vpermanent_prim_key WHERE 
    UCASE(NAME)='MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_PERMANENT_RESIDENCE_CERTIFICATE';  
    INSERT INTO     
 MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_SAVED_APPLICATION(SAVED_APPLICATION_ID,APPLICATION_NO,SERVICE_ID,SERVICE_ITEM_ID,PROCESSSTAGEID,IS_DOCUMENT_UPLOADED,IS_SUBMITTED,CREATEDBY,CREATEDATE,MODIFYBY,MODIFYDATE,CITIZEN_NAME,EXPECTED_DEL_DATE1,VIEW_APPLICATIN_URL)  
    VALUES(ventitymast_appno,in_app_no,1,vpermanent_prim_key,0,1,1,7,CURRENT_TIM
  ESTAMP,7,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,NULL,'');   
UPDATE MASTERTB.Z_ENTITYMAST_NEXT_SEQUENCE SET NEXT_SEQUENCE=ventitymast_appno   WHERE NAME= 'mastertb.Z_ENTITYMAST_SAVED_APPLICATION';    
    RELEASE SAVEPOINT STOP_HERE;    
--END TRANSACTION  
    SET out_response='S';       
END
```

Comment: i want to rollback first insert in case of error in second insert. please help as i am new to db2.

Comment: Is this procedure a part of a larger transaction? If so, the savepoint should be outside the procedure. If not, you don't need the savepoint.

Comment: sir when i run my procedure and if there is any mistake in second insert then also my first insert successfully insert the data, that i dont want. plz help